# PyQT5 Grahicsview coordinate system

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I'm trying to create a GUI with PyQT5 and Qt Designer. The most things work, but I have problems to understand the usage of Graphics View and Grahpics Scene.
I created the scene with the following code:

```
self.view.setAlignment(AlignTop | AlignLeft)
self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
self.scene.setSceneRect(-500, -500, 1000, 1000)
self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.red))
self.view.setScene(self.scene)
```

and added two points:

```
self.point_one = QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, 0, 30, 30)
self.point_one.setPos(500, 0)
self.view.addItem(self.point_one)

self.point_two = QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, 0, 30, 30)
self.point_two.setPos(-500, 0)
self.view.addItem(self.point_two)
```

the resize event handler:

```
def resizeEvent(self, event):
    self.view.fitInView(self.scene.sceneRect(), KeepAspectRatio)
```

I set a background color for the scene and can see, that the scene fills the view:

[image: current output]

But i expected, that the coordinates from the setSceneRect() call are used so the position (500, 0) is on the right side but it isn't:

[image: expected position]

How can I map the coordinates from the scene (-500 to 500) to the view?

Update:
If I leave out the 'KeepAspectRatio' from fitInView it works. The problem now is that the points doesn't automatically resize if I resize the window horizontally:

[image: scaling]

Are there any predefined functions available to rescale the points?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `setSceneRect()` doesn't mean that the specified rect corresponds to the full visible area in the view, but it's the area that the view can access. Since the view is wider than the visible rect, the result is that the "right" point is not at the right edge of the view, and that's because you're using `KeepAspectRatio`. Remove that and the right point will probably be where you expect it to be.

Comment: @musicamante It works without 'KeepAspectRatio' but then there is no rescaling of the points. I updated the question with a picture of what I mean.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't understand how the coordinate system of a graphics scene works, especially within a graphics view, which most probably won't have the same aspect ratio of the scene (including scroll bars). Besides, the "aspect ratio" flag has [3 possible values](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#AspectRatioMode-enum): have you considered using `KeepAspectRatioByExpanding`? I strongly urge you to read more about the [Graphics View Coordinate System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system) and ***all*** related classes (such as QAbstractScrollArea).